# use windowManager popeUp displayed over other Apps with jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-windowmanager

there is one help me to use windowManager for create popeUp like trucaller app displayed over other Apps with jetpack compose ?? becose I searched but I not fond any example in google

this is my code :

that code is not worked with me it give me error

```
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: LayoutNode should be attached to an owner
```

```
 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Composable
    fun MyApp() {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val window = context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        val layoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams().apply {
            type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
            format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            width = 400 // Set the desired width
            height = 300 // Set the desired height
        }
        val overlayView = rememberOverlayView(window, layoutParams)

        AndroidView(
            factory = {
                      overlayView

                
                      },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ){

        }

    }

    @Composable
    fun rememberOverlayView(window: WindowManager, layoutParams: WindowManager.LayoutParams): View {


        val context = LocalContext.current
        return remember {
            val overlayView = object : FrameLayout(context) {
                override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
                    super.onAttachedToWindow()
                    window.addView(this, layoutParams)
                    setContent {
                        ComposeOverlay()

                    }
                }

                override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
                    super.onDetachedFromWindow()
                    window.removeView(this)
                    // Clean up resources if needed
                }
            }

            if (overlayView.parent != null) {
                (overlayView.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(overlayView)
            }

            window.addView(overlayView, layoutParams)
            overlayView
        }
    }


    @Composable
    fun ComposeOverlay() {
  
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
            Text(text = "Hello from Compose!", color = Color.Black)
        }

    }
```

I asked chatGPt but not give me any solution right

Answer (score 0):

To display Jetpack compose as a floating view on top of others app, you can use this library [Floating-Bubble-View](https://github.com/TorryDo/Floating-Bubble-View) (I'm the author btw). This library supports both `XML` and `Jetpack Compose`, hope this helps.